# How can I parse such json dict?

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I have a dict in json format and need to get all **'src'** value from all dict. Dict is such format

```
{
  "response": {
    "165": {
      "photo": {
        "access_key": "25b928f75a3730a988", 
        "created": 1490195550, 
        "text": "", 
        "sizes": [
          {
            "src": "https://pp.userapi.com/xxxxx.jpg", 
            "height": 133, 
            "type": "p", 
            "width": 200
          }, 
        ], 
        "pid": 456239362, 
        "aid": -3, 
        "owner_id": 14793
      }, 
      "type": "photo"
    }, 
      "78": {
      "photo": {
        "access_key": "2cc06244975d01b54c", 
        "created": 1501701707, 
        "text": "", 
        "sizes": [
          {
            "src": "https://pp.userapi.com/xxxxx.jpg", 
            "height": 412, 
            "type": "p", 
            "width": 200
          }, 
        ], 
        "pid": 456239726, 
        "aid": -3, 
        "owner_id": 14793
      }, 
      "type": "photo"
    }
  }
}
```

I stuck with

```
photos = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response']
```

Dont know how to use the **for** method in this case
asdfsdfsdafsdafdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfsdafsadfsdafsdafsdafsadfs

Comment: What is the error information? The Dict seems not complete

Comment: please post a valid json, it is not valid.

Comment: `photos = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response']['165']['photo']['sizes'][0]['src']` must be what you are looking for

Comment: I will get object only from ['165']. How can I iterate all numbers in 'response' object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
photos = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response']
src = [i['photo']['sizes'][0]['src'] for i in photos.values()]
```

`src` will store a list of all the values.

*PS* : You could pull off a one-liner too, but it would look really messy

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @question1 That error occurs when you try to access a `list` using a non-integer index. Are you sure that is the correct `json` you have posted?

Answer (score 1):

Say x is the dictionary you provided.

```
x = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response']
```

This would be the way to extract sources:

```
sizes = [x[elem]['photo']['sizes'] for elem in x]
srcs = []
for size_list in sizes:
    for size_element in size_list:
        srcs.append(size_element['src'])
```

Comment: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: or string indices must be integers

Comment: Not sure why that would be happening as I wrote a code example for myself that works with the provided dictionary.

Comment: Are you still having problems parsing the dict? Here is a code example: https://repl.it/repls/LonelyGiantYorkshireterrier